# In chess lingo, should pieces be preceded with the "the" article?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I've noticed many native english speakers that are professional chess players saying things like:

> In this situation I can capture with pawn.

This just "sounds" very unnatural to me and I would say

> In this situation I can capture with **the** pawn.

I tried to go into whether it was countable/non countable but I couldn't find an answer by myself, I'm not even sure that's what would determine it.

My question is, do chess pieces need articles? Are there different situations where sometimes it's needed and sometimes not which I'm not noticing?

Comment: Native speakers, indeed chess players, do speak of _positions_ in chess, rather than _situations._

Comment: To the OP, are you talking about usage in chess literature, or in writing not solely directed at chess players? Or both?

Comment: The zero article version in this context sounds very unnatural to me too. However, in other contexts it may be more acceptable. For example, in _Learn Chess Volume Two: Winning Methods_ (p27) is the sentence: _...Black has king, queen and KP in line._

Comment: It's increasingly common in formal and especially telescopic writing. Essentially, the anarthrous version is a style choice here rather than incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, anarthrous is my first new word for today.

Comment: @StuartF TBH, it's pure curiosity just based on hearing English native people use it without the article.

Comment: FWIW, I completely disagree with the decision to close this question. It is an excellent question about normal and common English usage. There is nothing opinionated about it.

Comment: Were they Russian professional chess players?

Comment: @Jim The question does say "native english speakers". I know, I do the same thing all the time.

Comment: @BoldBen - Oops.

Comment: @FraserOrr I've complained to the moderators, but no word from them until now, I don't understand, this does not seem like an opinion based thing, it's either correct to say it without the article or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you hear this form commonly among chess experts, I'd suggest two possibilities (aside from sloppiness or error):

1. It is being used as a short hand staccato jargon: for example, in the movie Top Gun the protagonist is told over radio: "Maverick, do not engage bandit", rather than "the bandit".
2. "Pawn" is being used as the category of that piece rather than a specific piece. "Take the town with artillery" as opposed to "the artillery". In fact I did this in the previous point -- "told over radio" not "told over the radio."

I understand that "Top Gun" is not the Oxford English Dictionary, however, I think native speakers will recognize the structure that I am referring to.

I'm not a chess player myself, but these two options might explain what you hear.

Answer (score 1):

> I've noticed many native English speakers that are professional chess players saying things like: "In this situation I can capture with pawn."

I have found no examples of this on the internet. I would avoid it.

In this context, the idiomatic use would be countable and thus would need a determiner/quantifier or be in the plural.

"In this situation I can capture with **a/the** pawn."
"In this situation I can capture with pawn**s**."

The only context in which **pawn/bishop/knight**, etc appears to be uncountable would be with "by [means of]" that indicates the instrumental, e.g.

*"As the pawns surround the king, checking can only be done by knight."*

in which "knight" would be the class name of those pieces, but even so, this is not very idiomatic.

I would expect to hear "In this situation I can capture **the piece** with **a/the pawn/[the] pawn*s***."

Comment: That's true, especially as a player has the option of taking any given piece at any given time with a maximum of two pawns and usually only one.

Answer (score 0):

Chess literature is comparatively scanty but sufficient material exists to give sure indications; by considering as well the other pieces with  respect to this usage, as the generalization is legitimate, a more solid result can be arrived at.  The term "capture" is a standard term of the subject but belongs to a higher register, and as a consequence leaves no trace in chess literature. However the term "take" is common enough to allow a conclusion to be made.

**No case of zero article, and use of "the"**

**take with** (the) [pawn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+pawn%2Ctake+with++pawn&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20with%20the%20pawn%3B%2Cc0), [king](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+king%2Ctake+with+king&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20with%20the%20king%3B%2Cc0), [queen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+queen%2Ctake+with+queen&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20with%20the%20queen%3B%2Cc0), [knight](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+knight%2Ctake+with+knight&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20with%20the%20knight%3B%2Cc0)

**No record of either**

**take with** (the)  [bishop](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+bishop%2Ctake+with+bishop&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [castle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+castle%2Ctake+with+castle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [rook](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+with+the+rook%2Ctake+with+rook&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)

**capture with** (the) [pawn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+pawn%2Ctake+with+pawn&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [king](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+king%2Ctake+with+king&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [queen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+queen%2Ctake+with+queen&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [bishop](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+bishop%2Ctake+with+bishop&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [knight](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+knight%2Ctake+with+knight&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), [castle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+castle%2Ctake+with+castle&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3), [rook](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capture+with+the+rook%2Ctake+with+rook&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)

In consequence of what the literature reveals the article must be used. Moreover, dictionaries do not reckon with the word "pawn" as an uncount noun.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pawn_1?q=pawn))  chess piece of the smallest size and least value.
> ♦ Each player has eight pawns at the start of a game.
> ♦ He had to sacrifice another pawn.

As far as I know this "uncountable" usage is not found, but, of course I am far from listening to chess commentaries on a professional basis. I'd say that this could be a budding usage, but no more. I would recommend not to follow it. It is perfectly equivalent to the case of a one chair room and of someone who would  say in relation to this state of affairs  "When I am tired I sit on chair." (for the least very unnatural).

Comment: @PeterShor This is true too, it's a telegraphic style that is useful; however in discussions where le value of the various possibilities are being assessed that is not necessarily what one uses; then normal language is also used.